# Bootstrap4, btn and btn-primary classes don't work for link ("a" tag)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap version 4.1, there are no custom styles in my page. Here is the code for displaying buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
<a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="{% url 'website_admin_create_user' %}">
    <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;{% trans 'Add user' %}
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#listFilter" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="listFilter">
    <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>&nbsp;{% trans 'Filters' %}
</button>
```

The problem is that, style for `a` tag is not working, despite I can see it in browser inspector. What might cause such behavior?

[image: boostrap 4 link style]

[image: inspector tab]

Comment: The only possible reason the above could happen is you are using href on some condition. and if on anchor tag you don't mention href then it behaves like a disable button. So what max i could assume out of this is that there is some lag while the css is updated and href value is achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: `type="button"` caused this mess, just remove it and everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a button css class on an `<a>` tag just switch it to `<button>` no need for an `<a>`

Comment: Actually `<a>` works with the button classes as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#button-tags

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to

```
<a href="{% url 'website_admin_create_user' %}">
   <button  class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;{% trans 'Add user' %}
   </button>
</a>
```

instead of

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" href="{% url 'website_admin_create_user' %}">
     <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp;{% trans 'Add user' %}
</a>
```

Comment: Actually `<a>` works with the button classes as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#button-tags